# Java call a method on sibling classes

Tags: java

Good Day,

I have tried good google searches, and even some reading, but not exactly sure how to proceed. Here is the problem:

When i call `duplicate()` on any implementation of java.nio.Buffer, the byte order I had set with the original buffer `buf.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN)` is not preserved. This is a problem. So I set out to create a static method that will allow me to do the following like this example:

```
public static ByteBuffer endianPreservingDuplicate(ByteBuffer b){
    ByteOrder holder = b.order();
    ByteBuffer ret = b.duplicate();
    ret.order(holder);
    return ret;
}
```

This works, but is there any actual way to do this (generics maybe?) without having to implement this function for every type (ByteBuffer, FloatBuffer, IntBuffer, etc)?

Comment: The duplicate method is not a method from a base class or interface that is common to all these buffers, so I don't seee how it would be possible (except with reflection, but you don't want to do that: it's ugly).

Comment: Thanks, I did not realize this until you pointed it out :) . I will just be implementing the methods where it applies by hand then. Is there any reason why it makes sense not to preserve the byte order that is set by the "parent" buffer?

Comment: Perhaps use a less strict language for your duplicate function such as Groovy?  You could write your endianPreservingDuplicate function such that, as long as the class you pass in has an order() and duplicate() method, your function would work.

Comment: @BillJames That's actually exactly what the Java code in my answer (theoretically) does.

Comment: @Vulcan Yes you did, and oh LORD wouldn't it have been easier in Groovy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a combination of generics and reflection, but it's ugly:

```
public static <T extends Buffer> T endianPreservingDuplicate(T b) throws Exception {
    Class<?> clazz = b.getClass();
    Method getOrder = getMethod(clazz, "order");
    ByteOrder orderTemp = (ByteOrder) getOrder.invoke(b);
    Method duplicate = getMethod(clazz, "duplicate");
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // cast is safe
    T copy = (T) duplicate.invoke(b);
    Method setOrder = getMethod(clazz, "order", ByteOrder.class);
    setOrder.invoke(copy, orderTemp);
    return copy;
}

private static Method getMethod(Class<?> clazz, String name, Class<?>...params) throws NoSuchMethodException {
    try {
        Method method = clazz.getDeclaredMethod(name, params);
        method.setAccessible(true);
        return method;
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        Class<?> superclass = clazz.getSuperclass();
        if (!superclass.equals(Buffer.class)) {
            return getMethod(superclass, name, params);
        } else {
            throw new NoSuchMethodException("no " + name + " method");
        }
    }
}
```

It will throw an exception if a Buffer implementation without `order()` or `duplicate()` is passed as the `b` parameter.

The best option is to make individual methods for each buffer type.

Partial credits to [ruakh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/978917/ruakh) for reviewing the code and suggesting updates.

Comment: thanks. this is perfect. as pointed out before, I now realize the method signature for order doesnt exist for most of the buffer types, but this is actually what I was looking for in technique. Thanks again :)

Comment: This won't even compile, because it tries to call `order(ByteOrder)` nonreflectively. The `clazz.cast(ret)` doesn't help with that; actually, it just makes it worse, because `clazz` has type `Class<?>`, so the expression `clazz.cast(ret)` has compile-time type `?` (i.e. effectively `Object`). Instead, you need to reflectively get *both* `order` methods, the one with a parameter and the one without, and invoke each of them reflectively.

Comment: @ruakh Nice point out, I'm not sure why I wrote it to invoke anything non-reflectively; I've updated the code.

Comment: The new version is much closer, but it still doesn't work. You see, something like `ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[1024])` returns an instance of a non-`public` subclass of `ByteBuffer`, rather than an instance of `ByteBuffer` directly (`ByteBuffer` is `abstract`, so every instance of it is actually of a subclass). When that happens, this method will raise an `IllegalAccessException` because it tries to invoke a method on that non-`public` subclass, even though the method itself is `public`. So instead of just writing `Class<?> clazz = b.getClass()`, you need to use *[continued]*

Comment: *[continued]* `Class#getSuperclass()` to walk up the class hierarchy until you reach a class whose `public` methods you can invoke. (Since `public` non-`static` methods are always virtual in Java, this will end up invoking the subclass method, but it will do so in a way that the runtime environment can allow.)

Comment: Thanks again @ruakh.  I've updated the code and confirmed it now works as designed.  For simplicity, I used `#getDeclaredMethod` and `#setAccessible` instead of looking for public methods.

Comment: `setAccessible(true)` is totally cheating, but O.K.; at least you've managed to drive home the main point, which is that this approach is way too ugly. :-P

Comment: By the way, you might want to give the method a generic signature, `public static <T extends Buffer> T endianPreservingDuplicate(T b) throws Exception {`, so that it can be called like `ByteBuffer bb2 = endianPreservingDuplicate(bb1)` rather than requiring the caller to cast the return-value. (For this you can write `(T) clazz.cast(duplicate.invoke(b))`. That's technically an unchecked cast, in that the compiler can't tell that it's typesafe, but it *is* typesafe, so you can just tack on `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`.)

Comment: Nice idea, I've added that.  I'd share some of the accepted-answer reputation if I could, but I already upvoted your answer even before writing my own.

Comment: Groovy ftw!  This is like 3 or 4 lines in Groovy.

Answer (score 2):

So far as the compiler can tell, there is no relationship between the `duplicate` method on these various classes; they're not defined by any supertype (superclass or interface). Their only commonality, therefore, is in their method signature (name and parameters), and the only way to access that is via reflection. And similarly for `order`. This would be possible, but would be very messy, and would interfere with your IDE's ability to help you see what your code is doing; it's probably not worth it.

Furthermore, there's an even bigger problem: your method depends on `ByteBuffer#order(ByteOrder)` to set the byte order; but `FloatBuffer` and `IntBuffer` don't even *have* such a method. They do have an `order()` that takes no arguments and returns their byte order, but they don't have an `order(ByteOrder)` that takes a byte order and adopts it. (This is because their byte order isn't really their own: if they're wrappers around a byte buffer, then they use its byte order, and if they're wrappers around arrays, they use the system's byte order.)

So the good news is . . . you don't need to implement this method for every type, because you can't. :-P

Comment: Thanks! I do not understand at all why byte order is not preserved in a duplicate() though, it makes no sense, especially if pretty much everything else is copied to the new view on the buffer.